# If is it possible to get BGR from MediaCodec?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

As far as I know, `MediaCodec` return output buffer of image in `YUV420` and then you can process with it as you like to... But in my case I need to convert `YUV420` in `BGR`, it is quite expensive conversion.

So, question is if it is possible immediately (without conversion) get `BGR` from `MediaCodec`?

My code now

```
uint8_t *buf = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(m_data.codec, static_cast<size_t>(status), /*bufsize*/nullptr);
cv::Mat YUVframe(cv::Size(m_frameSize.width, static_cast<int>(m_frameSize.height * 1.5)), CV_8UC1, buf);

cv::Mat colImg(m_frameSize, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(YUVframe, colImg, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 3);
auto dataSize = colImg.rows * colImg.cols * colImg.channels();
imageData.assign(colImg.data, colImg.data + dataSize);
```

So, as you can see here

```
cv::Mat YUVframe(cv::Size(m_frameSize.width, static_cast<int>(m_frameSize.height * 1.5)), CV_8UC1, buf);
```

I am getting `YUVframe` from codec buffer and then here

```
cv::cvtColor(YUVframe, colImg, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 3);
```

I make conversion

Conversion take a lot of time. For me performance is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frames come out of MediaCodec in whatever format the codec likes to work in.  Most digital cameras and video codecs work with YUV format frames.  The camera is required to use one of two specific formats when capturing still images, but MediaCodec is more of a free-for-all.  If you want the data to be in a specific format, something has to do the conversion.

On Android you can get the hardware to do it for you by involving the GPU, which is required to accept whatever format MediaCodec decides to generate on that device.  You latch each frame as an "external" texture by feeding it into a SurfaceTexture, and then tell GLES to render it in RGB on a pbuffer, which you can then access in different ways.  For an example that uses `glReadPixels()`, see [ExtractMpegFramesTest](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest).

There are alternatives to `glReadPixels()` that rely on private native methods to access the pbuffer (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25564203/294248) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21151259/294248)), but using non-public APIs is unwise unless you have complete control of the device.

There may be some newer approaches for accessing the pbuffer that I haven't used, e.g. using [native hardware buffers](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer) seems potentially useful ([or maybe not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43507536/294248)).

Comment: hello! Could you please take a look at this bound question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57653901/5709159 Thanks