# AMediaExtractor setDataSource AMEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED error on Android Q

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec, android-10.0, mediaextractor

I am working with `AMediaCodec` and `AMediaExtractor`, all works fine on all devices(I hope:), but if I check the same code on Android Q (in my case Pixel 2XL) I got such error `AMEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED`.

What I do

```
bool NativeCodec::createStreamingMediaPlayer(const std::string &filename)
{
    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    media_status_t err = 
      AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(ex, filename.c_str());;  <-- Here media status I got AMEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED 

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "ERROR", "ERROR ::: %s", std::to_string(err).c_str());
        return false;
    }

    .....
}
```

Maybe this is somehow connected with privicy that was introduced in Android Q, but I didn't find any info about it...

How to check this issue?

Comment: There are three different places in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-q-preview-6/media/ndk/NdkMediaExtractor.cpp#86) for `AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractor, const char*)` that return that error, all of which are preceded by an ALOGE. Do you see errors in logcat? I think the only plausible one is the thread complaint, but the error may be coming from farther down the stack.

Comment: @fadden Yes, I get an error `NdkMediaExtractor: can't create http service`... So, it is means that issue not in `setDataSource()` method... I checked `MediaExtractor` implementation and did not find such error... And it is odd because why create http service? I don't use any http connections... any suggestions? And also interesting that on other devices it is works fine... Or problem in Pixel 2XL or in Android Q...

Comment: The argument to `setDataSource()` is a URI, not a filename. The HTTP service object will resolve it as a local file if possible. The INTERNET permission check should only matter if it resolves to a non-local file, but you might try fiddling with permissions to see if it makes a difference. (See the source code linked earlier. Oddly, I'm not seeing an error message that says "can't create" there, just "can't find".)

Comment: @fadden it is strange, because I acctually have `INTERNET` permission on my `Manifest` file, this permission is `normal`, so it doesn't require to ask user about permission it is granted by default...

Comment: @fadden it looks like Android bug... Or Q of Pixel... But actually for now I don't have another Android Q device to check it.

Answer (score 5):

This to me seems a bug on Android 10. It seems that `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` does not change the situation. You may have to request `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/>` on manifest and ask same permission at runtime. The `AMediaExtractor_setDataSource` function must be called on a thread that is attached to Java. Doing all of that correctly will allow you to make it work on other versions of Android but not on Android 10. I've reported the issue on Android Bug Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/144837266
As per google answer, it seems that all the app using native libraries that require file access through path can be affected and they know the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94 .

A workaround in my case was to use `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd`, getting the file descriptor at Java level through `contentResolver` and its method `openFileDescriptor`.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this answer put me on the right track. What confuses me is that I can just do this right before calling the extractor:
`FILE* testFile = fopen(fullPath.c_str(), "r"); int fd = fileno(testFile);`
I then use `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` with this descriptor without problems.
What I gathered from the whole Android 10 scoped storage ordeal is that I should not be able to do this, or do I miss something here? It might be a special case since I'm only reading files, not writing.
Tested this on Android 10 on a real device (Pixel) and emulator.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to you not specifying a Java thread to be used. Create the thread and then attach it via `AttachCurrentThread`

Comment: I have invoked `AttachCurrentThread`, but why it is works on all other devices?